# multiple file upload to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to do multiple file upload simultaneously to google big-query using command line tool. I got following error :

BigQuery error in load operation: Could not connect with BigQuery server.
Http response status: 503
Http response content:
Service Unavailable

Any way to workaround this problem ?

How do I upload multiple files simultaneously to google big-query using command line tool.

Comment: For the most robust uploads, I would recommend first uploading into Google Cloud Storage and then using the BQ CLI to import the files. Can you paste the exact commands you are using?

Comment: I am using bq load --field_delimiter='\t' <project-id>:<dataset>.<table> schema

Answer (score 2):

Multiple file upload should work (and we use it every day). If you're getting a 503, that indicates something is wrong with the service. One thing you might want to make sure of is that if you're using a `*` in your command line that you have it quoted so that the shell doesn't expand it automatically before it gets passed to bq.

If you're getting a 503 error, can you retry the command the flag `--apilog=-` (this needs to be one of the first params) which will dump the interaction with the server to stdout. The problem may be obvious from that log, but if it isn't can you update your question with the relevant portions of the log? If you're not comfortable posting that information on a public forum, can you e-mail it to me at tigani at google dot com?